# Substitution to write out powers of expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am looking for a substitution command which will write out powers of expressions like this:

$$\frac{a ~b^3~ c}{d~ e^{3/2}~ f^2}\to \frac{a ~b~b~b~ c}{d~ e^{1/2}~ e^{1/2}~ e^{1/2}~ f~f}$$

mathematica code to experiment with:

```
(a b^3 c)/(d e^(3/2) f^2)
```

Please note, this is needed to carry out substitutions on very large expressions, so that a `ComplexityFunction` is not an option since a `Simplify` will take forever to evaluate.

**EDIT**

I want to do this since I plan to apply substitutions for expressions like

$$\frac{a b}{e^{1/2}}\to q ~~~\text{ and } ~~~\frac{b}{e^{1/2}f}\to p$$

which do not get recognized while all the terms are cluttered into one heap.

**EDIT2**

Maybe, as some point to start with, I should ask how to make mathematica take some literate input without performing any kind of simplification to it. Such that an input $b+b$ would still display as $b+b$ instead of the automatic $2b$? Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you plan to do with that expression after the replacement?

Comment: Is it for display only? If not, Mathematica will reevaluate something like `b b` to `b^2` automatically

Comment: I plan to apply substitutions for expressions like $\frac{a b}{e^{1/2}}\to q$ and $\frac{b}{e^{1/2}f}\to p$ which do not get recognized while all the terms are cluttered into one heap.

Comment: Won't those substitutions depend on lexical order?

Comment: I checked that `(a b c)/(d e g) /. (a b)/e -> q` works fine. Problems come up if the powers are not matching.

Comment: Have you tried `Eliminate`?

Comment: It seems `Eliminate` requires equations as input. I do not have equations - just a huge expression where I would like to substitute expressions into.

Comment: I didn't understand but it seems others did

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
Repeat[x_, n_] := Row@ConstantArray[x, {n}];
expr /. Power[x_, Rational[p_, q_] | p_] :> Repeat[x^(Sign[p]/(1*q)), Abs@p]
```

where `expr` is your expression. This will display things the way you wanted. If you don't need things to be displayed, you can just leave the `Repeat` function undefined.

Comment: Works great on some power of a square root but with something like `(e^(3/2) b^3)/a^2` it reverses the sign in the exponent of $b$ and $a$. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That is very strange. Variable `q` should have default value `1`. However, it is undefined and for some reason `Sign[p]/q` ends up equal to `-1`. Let me see how to fix this.

Comment: Even removing the `Sign` around `p` still gives `-1`.

Comment: It seems that the default value `1` for `q` made no difference so I removed it. I'm not sure what `q` is initialized to now. However, I multiplied it by `1` and it somehow magically works. I'm not sure what is going on here. It could be a bug (maybe you should post that as a separate question).

Comment: `MatchQ[-2, Rational[2, -1]] == True` so maybe there is some overinterpretation

Comment: I think the problem was that the full form of `p/q` is `Times[Power[q,-1],p]`. When `q` is undefined, this returns `-p` which caused the problem.

Comment: Using structural modifications (rule replacements) for mathematical gymnastics is not a good idea and usually works only for the simplest of cases. You'll always run into cases where it doesn't work, which forces you to keep modifying/extending the pattern, which is an endless game. The correct way to approach OP's problem would be via Solve/Reduce/Eliminate, etc.

Comment: I just realized that the function `Row` just displays the terms. It converts them to a kind of picture (one can even insert a frame in the options). While it still is impressive, what I am looking for is such an option for mathematical expressions which will retain the mathematical context of the expression...

Comment: Then you have to explain what you need this for. If you just wanted to perform some operations on expressions in this form and then get back to their algebraic meaning, you can apply `% /. Row[lst__] :> Times @@ lst`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for exercise. It works only with products but I believe it can be eaily extended. Also for exercise, because I think rm -rf is right about approach.

I've taken Māris Ozols formula and extended it.

**EDIT:**  it works now with integer and rational powers

```
sub[expr_, parts_, var_] := Module[{reduce, p, n, list, ct, red, l2},
   reduce := {If[MatchQ[Head[#], Symbol], 1, #] & /@ # /. 
              Power[_, y_] :> y, # /. Power[x_, y_] :> x}\[Transpose] &;
p = reduce@parts;
n = reduce@Cases[expr, Times[l_] :> l];

list = n /. {x_, a_?(MemberQ[p[[All, 2]], #] &)} :> With[
   {en = Select[n, MatchQ[#[[2]], a] &][[1, 1]], 
    pn = Select[p, #[[2]] == a &][[1, 1]]},
   If[Floor[en/pn] >= 0, 
      {Table[a^pn, {i, Floor[en/pn]}]~Join~{a^Mod[en, pn]}},
      a]
   ] // Flatten;
ct = Min[Count[list, #] & /@ parts];
red = Nest[{(i = #[[2]] + 1; 
            DeleteCases[#[[1]], parts[[i]], 1, ct]), i} &, {list, 0}, 
           Length@parts][[1]];
l2 = red~Join~Table[var, {i, ct}];
Times @@ l2]
```

so lets check it:

```
expr=(a b^3 c)/(d e^(3/2) f^2);
parts={a,b,e^(-1/2)}; (*parts of element to replace*)


sub[expr,parts, q]
```

In output there should be expr with a*b/(e^(-1/2)) replaced by q. It works for me.

If someone has suggestions how to improve this code (not this answer, only code, different functions or comends etc.), thanks in advance.